# algorithm to map weighted objects to their amount

Tags: algorithm

need algorithm to map weighted objects to their amount and need to make amount minimal for each object with keeping ratio between weights

**example 1:**

```
input: object1: 40, object2: 60, object3: 80 
output: object1: 2, object2: 3, object3: 4
```

this can be solved by dividing object weight with gcd of weights of all objects

---

**example 2:**

```
input: object1: 3, object2: 15
output: object1: 1, object2: 5
```

---

**example 3:**

```
input: object1: 13, object2: 97, object3: 20
output: object1: 1, object2: 7, object3: 2
```

---

**example 4:**

```
input: object1: 1, object2: 17, object3: 97
output: object1: 0, object2: 1, object3: 5
```

---

gcd is not applicable for example 3 and 4, what's the algorithm can be used, is there any idea?

---

limitations: range of weights 0-99, maximum sum of all amounts is 32

Comment: What does "map weighted object to their amount" mean? Are you trying to average the number of objects by proportional weight?, Are yo trying to maximize the weight carried? Something else?  Please clarify your question and provide the logic behind your examples.

Comment: What are your requirements? If you need integers that preserve the ratios exactly, then you can't do better than dividing by the GCD. If you can compromise on needing integers and have some tolerance for ratios being slightly different then there are things you could try. E.g., dividing everything by the smallest input at whatever decimal accuracy you care to use.

Comment: @Dave I need this "If you can compromise on needing integers and have some tolerance for ratios", dividing by the smallest input does not fit, I need minimum amount of each object with keeping ratios

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping ratios"? Your examples 3 and 4 are not keeping ratios.

Comment: @k314159 keep ration approximately, because I cannot exceed total amount 32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, dividing by the GCD is the best you can do if you need integers that exactly preserve the ratio.

For floats that are very close to the ratio, divide everything by the min.

Ruby example:

```
def f(weights)
  min_wt = weights.min
  ans = []
  weights.each do |wt|
    ans.append(wt.to_f/min_wt)
  end
  return ans
end

> f([40, 60, 80])
=> [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]

> f([13, 97, 20])
=> [1.0, 7.461538461538462, 1.5384615384615385]
```

Alternate approach to get integers: Check every scaling factor in your range (final sum 1-32). I'm taking 1 as the floor for each integer since dividing by 0 is undefined.

Ruby code (not beautifully written):

```
def f(unsorted_weights)
  weights = unsorted_weights.sort!
  orig_sum_of_wts = weights.sum
  best_error = Float::INFINITY
  best_sum_of_wts = 0
  1.upto(32) do |new_sum_of_wts|
    error = 0.0
    new_wts = []
    0.upto(weights.length - 1) do |i|
      new_wts[i] = [1, weights[i] * new_sum_of_wts / orig_sum_of_wts].max
    end
    0.upto(weights.length - 2) do |i|
      new_wt_i = weights[i] * new_sum_of_wts / orig_sum_of_wts
      (i+1).upto(weights.length - 1) do |j|
        new_wt_j = weights[j] * new_sum_of_wts / orig_sum_of_wts
        error += (new_wts[j].to_f / [new_wts[i], 1.0].max - weights[j].to_f / [weights[i], 1.0].max).abs 
        
      end
      if error < best_error
        best_sum_of_wts = new_sum_of_wts
        best_error = error
      end
    end
  end
  ans = []
  0.upto(weights.length - 1) do |i|
    ans.append([1, weights[i] * best_sum_of_wts / orig_sum_of_wts].max)
  end
  puts "#{ans.to_s}"
end
```

Results:

```
> f([40, 60, 80])
[2, 3, 4]

> f([40, 60])
[2, 3]

> f([13, 97, 20])
[2, 3, 15]

> f([1, 17, 97])
[1, 4, 26]
```

For 13, 20, 97, I get 2,3,15 vs your 1,2,7.

```
Ratios: 20/13 = 1.538,  3/2 = 1.500, 2/1 = 2.000
        97/13 = 7.462, 15/2 = 7.500, 7/1 = 7.000
        97/20 = 4.850, 15/3 = 5.000, 7/2 = 3.500

Cumulative error for 2,3,15: 0.038 + 0.038 + 0.150 = 0.226
Cumulative error for 1,2,7:  0.038 + 0.462 + 1.350 = 2.274
```

Comment: I'm not worrying about zeroes or negatives here, but you should avoid dividing by zero by finding the min excluding zeroes. Up to you how to handle negatives; I'd suggest finding the non-zero min of the absolute values & dividing by that.

Comment: I have updated limitations in question, also need normalize to some sum, that total amount not upper than 32 for example

Comment: @Ildar Modified to give the best integer outputs in your range with no zeros.

Comment: This is not an efficient approach but it doesn't need to be unless you're going be running this on much bigger lists. All I'm doing is checking each scaling factor and returning the scaled list with the best error.

Comment: @Ildar This differs from your output on your 3rd and 4th examples. On the third, this has a better error. On the fourth, I skipped any solution with zeros since dividing by zero is undefined. If you have some methodology for handling ratios where the denominator is zero then share it and I can modify the code.

Comment: I will have no more than 8 objects, should be efficient, ok, I need think about your solution

Comment: could you pls explain main idea of this algorithm how it works

Comment: @Ildar Which one? The second?

Comment: yes, second algorithm

Comment: @Ildar In the second, we calculate the error for each of the possible scaling factors, find which one has the least cumulative error, and use that.